# Google Contacts API - No Redirection

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, authsub, google-contacts-api

I am currently working on Contact Importer web app (in PHP) so I will be able to grab email address from a user's account on Gmail, Yahoo, etc and use them for my own evil purposes. Just kidding, my web app is very friendly.

I thought I would start with Google. I found they have a fantastic little API called Google Contacts API which lets a programmer, like myself, to access a user's contacts.

After a couple of hours of struggling and throwing shitty code together, I ran into a few road-blocks. My main question is this:

*Is there any way that I can have a user provide their username and password for Gmail on my website and have my code retrieve the contacts **without** that nasty redirection to a Google login page? It's kind of ruins the whole flow of my web app.*

I've looked into AuthSub, and gotten that to work, but of course the catch is that you have to redirect the user to obtain the access token. It looks like OAuth will have this same catch.

The one ray of hope I have is the ClientLogin method of authentication. Again, there is a catch, sometimes Google throws you a CAPTCHA instead of the auth token. Again, the user flow is ruined.

I've noticed that our good ol' friends over at Twitter have it working just fine. Does anyone know how they do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I just settle for three-legged authentication. This seems to be the way the industry is moving.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you've identified a feature, not a bug.  The whole point of OAuth is to prevent users from typing their passwords into third-party sites like yours: this way they can learn to only type their Google password when they're looking at a Google login page and not have to trust that you won't store their password and use it to read all of their email.

It does provide a small interruption in the flow of your web app, but OAuth generally provides a callback so that it shouldn't really be a large disruption.  In exchange, your users can feel safer and you can avoid any issues of having to store (and then dispose of) user passwords.

In short, I don't think you'll be able to get around this.  It's true that Twitter does currently allow it ("Basic Auth", where the username and password are sent directly), but that feature is planned to be [deprecated by this summer](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-FAQ).